# How to make Asset.car file with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, assets

Is there any command or tool to make the Asset.car file ?
I've found **actool** but even when i run with no error, it doesn't give me the output file.
Please help. Many thanks.

For more information, what i need is the way to extract the ipa file, change some asset files and zip it back to the ipa file. But for the new versions of Xcode, the asset files is built to Asset.car file so i cannot only copy the assets to the extracted file

Comment: It's difficult to help. Can you give us the essential code parts?

Comment: Thank Ulrich. What i need is the way to extract the ipa file, change some asset files and zip it back to the ipa file. But for the new versions of Xcode, the asset files is built to Asset.car file so we cannot only copy the assets to the extracted file. Any idea ?